# Regarding selenium commands

Tags: selenium, browser-automation

I am new to Selenium automation. I have some queries to be clarified.

I have recorded and done the play back. Issue is as below:

If I use the **`clickAndWait`** command in Selenium IDE, it shows an error and continues for further execution, and the test case gets passed. Why does this sort of thing happen?

Another thing is, could I get fruitful Java code, if I export this kind of test case (having errors) using Java/Junit4/Web Driver from Selenium IDE?

Comment: Will you please elaborate the error or situation so that answering that will be easier. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error it shows?

Comment: Regarding exporting to Java, I Googled for `selenium IDE export to Java` and found 
[this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/6-0OUViPzkQ).

Comment: There is more information here also: http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your given info, I can draw following conclusion :

This type of error may come up after using **clickAndWait** when the whole page is not refreshed.

For Eg : When you click on any button, then it will just give you a popup, in that case AJAX will be called and the complete page is not refreshed. For such situation you may get the error.

If you want to remove or bypass the error you can use **waitForElementPresent** to make visible that element so that your test will essentially wait for the particular element.

(*A detailed description would be nice so that the answer can be given exactly*)

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two questions,

1. For first I am agree with [Talktokets answer.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/6417/5773). For safety, you can use waitForElementPresent.
2. For second, yes you can use the exported java code. For beginners it will be fruitfull.  After sometime, you can learn to edit/modify these codes according to your use, and then you can write such codes by your own efficiently.